# split and flatten array of comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

What is the best way to convert:

```js
const a = ["jan,feb,may", "apr,may,sept,oct", "nov,jan,mar", "dec", "oct,feb,jan"]
```

to

```js
const res = ["jan","feb","may","apr","may","sept","oct","nov","jan","mar","dec","oct","feb","jan"]
```

PS: in javascript, I tried using `array.reduce()` and split method. but that didn't work. here is what I tried

```js
let flat = arr.reduce((arr, item) => [...arr, ...item.split(',')]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could just join and split again:

```js
const a = ["jan,feb,may", "apr,may,sept,oct", "nov,jan,mar", "dec", "oct,feb,jan"];

const res = a.join().split(',');

console.log(res);
```

Or implicitly joining:

```js
const a = ["jan,feb,may", "apr,may,sept,oct", "nov,jan,mar", "dec", "oct,feb,jan"];

const res = "".split.call(a, ",");

console.log(res);
```

Or implicitly joining when splitting with [a regex method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@split):

```js
const a = ["jan,feb,may", "apr,may,sept,oct", "nov,jan,mar", "dec", "oct,feb,jan"];

const res = /,/[Symbol.split](a);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const a = ["jan,feb,may", "apr,may,sept,oct", "nov,jan,mar", "dec", "oct,feb,jan"];

const res = a.flatMap(e => e.split(','));

console.log(res);
```